# Using cmake for a project with sub/external projects/dependencies

Tags: c++, cmake

I am actually imroving my c++ skills with a project that uses [PocoProject](http://pocoproject.org/) as a framework for supplying a simple rest webserver and json parsing as well as a mongodb driver.

I am compiling my project with cmake/make

my directory structure is:

```
root
 - pocoproject
 - helloworld.cpp
 - CMakeLists.txt
```

To test cmake, I have a simple cpp file (taken from the poco examples) that starts a http-server. the includes are the following:

```
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServer.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPRequestHandler.h"
...
#include "Poco/Util/HelpFormatter.h"
#include <iostream>
```

My CMakeLists.txt look like:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (Hello)
add_executable(Hello helloworld.cpp)
```

### Question:

How do I add the needed libraries from pocoproject to to my executable? How do I reference the headers correctly?

Comment: Link libraries using [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html). You don't need to do anything if your headers reside in the same directory as the cpp files, otherwise use [include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html).

Comment: So I would need to add a target_link_libraries rule per header and add the pocoproject folder that the includes are valid?

Comment: For most 3d-party libraries, all their headers are located in the single directory (*include directory*), and are implemented in single *library* file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need let your CMake project know where to look for the dependencies, such as Poco. You need to set the variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. It can be done with `cmake-gui` or on the command line:

```
cmake ... -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=<path> ...
```

The `<path>` is where you copied or installed the Poco library, so the Poco headers will have paths like `<path>/include/Poco/AbstractCache.h`, etc..., libraries like `<path>/lib/libPocoFoundation.*` and most importantly, the config-module must be found at `<path>/lib/cmake/Poco/PocoConfig.cmake`.

In your `CMakeLists.txt` you need to find the Poco package with

```
find_package(Poco REQUIRED Foundation Util Net)
```

and link to it with

```
target_link_libraries(Hello Poco::Foundation Poco::Util Poco::Net)
```